# How to limit windows/smb share network speed

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-shares, smb, sharing

I have shared some of my files like Movies and Songs on local Network in my hostel, so that my friends can watch those movies.

Now sometime it happens that when someone is copying the shared files then I am not able to watch videos on YouTube or do any other internet surfing reliably.

Is there some way to limit/cap/prioritise Windows 10 share speed. I know I can use third party software to share but I was wondering if Windows itself provide any such kind of feature ?

Answer (score 2):

The network term is called Qos  or Quality of Service.  For the best options and compatibility I would suggest adding a router or switch with Qos built-in.  However,windows does have these options.

[image: gpedit.msc]

[image: new policy]

Comment: But as description says it will apply DSCP marking on all outbound HTTP, UDP, TCP traffic, I was looking if something is supported by Windows File Sharing which applies only on File Sharing Traffic. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: You misunderstood that dialog box. When clicking through the assistant, you will be able to set the ports which will be affected. If you set the ports for SMB/NB there, only your "File Sharing" traffic will be limited.